# Convergence of the improper integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{p-1}}{1+qx}dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

I found that the following converges where ${0<p<1}$,and ${0<q}$, but I'm having some trouble where q is negative.

Because it has some "blow up" point,    it seems to diverge, but i'm not sure.

Any help will be greatly appreciate.

$$\int \limits_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{p-1}}{1+qx}dx$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly $q$ should be greater or equal $0$.

Moreover, if $q=0$ we have
$$\frac{x^{p-1}}{1+qx}=\frac1{x^{1-p}}\not\in L^1(0,\infty),\;\forall p$$
and if $q>0$ then
$$\frac{x^{p-1}}{1+qx}\sim_\infty \frac1q\frac{1}{x^{2-p}}\in L^1([1,\infty))\iff 2-p>1\iff p<1$$
and
$$\frac{x^{p-1}}{1+qx}\sim_0\frac1{x^{1-p}}\in L^1(0,1)\iff 1-p<1\iff 0<p$$

**Conclusion**
The given integral exists if and only if $(0<p<1)\land (q>0)$.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer, but could you explain why q should not have a negative value?

Comment: In the case $q<0$ the function 
$$x\mapsto \frac{x^{p-1}}{1+qx}$$
isn't defined on $(0,\infty)$  so the given integral diverges.

Comment: Thank you again. May be I didn't understand the definition of the improper integral completely. Then how about $\int \limits_{-1}^{1}\frac{1}{x}dx=0$ ?

Comment: No this integral doesn't exist since $x\mapsto\frac1x$ isn't defined on $0$ and perhaps you confuse with the notion of [Cauchy principal value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value).

Comment: Thank you for your answering!! have a nice day sir

Comment: You're welcome.